# how to do pagination and search based on status on rturk gem for mturk?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, rubygems, mechanicalturk

we are working with rturk gem to get hit from mturk in ruby

```
rturk gem : https://github.com/ryantate/rturk
```

I able to get hit from mturk using below code

```
hits = RTurk::Hit.all
puts "#{hits.size} hits. \n"
```

but it gives me only 100 hits how to find pagination object and total count of hits using rturk gem

how we can manage pagination with rturk ?
using the above code it gives all results but i want to search hits based on specific states.
How we can search for a hit by its state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Mechanical Turk has a max page size of 100 ([details here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SearchHITsOperation.html)), so that's why the rturk gem is faithfully returning 100 HITs.

The `RTurk::SearchHITs` operation does not seem to support searching by status. Instead, you can use the `RTurk::GetReviewableHITs` operation to do something like this:

```
    get_reviewable_hits = RTurk::GetReviewableHITs.new status: 'Reviewable', page_size: 10, page_number: 2
    => #<RTurk::GetReviewableHITs:0x007faacb523668 @status="Reviewable", @page_number=2, @page_size=10>

    request = get_reviewable_hits.request

    request.total_num_results
    => 91

    request.num_results
    => 10

    hits = request.hit_ids.map { |id| RTurk::Hit.new(id) }
    hits_with_details_and_assignments = request.hit_ids.map { |id| RTurk::Hit.find(id) }
```

Here we're:

- filtering by status `Reviewable`
- setting the page size to 10 to demonstrate pagination, as I only had 91 reviewable HITs handy
- requesting page 2 of 9 for illustration

Hope this helps. Cheers.